# The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full when comparing large data. (around 10 million rows in each table)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables with these columns, each table has rows around 10 million.

```
Table A

Id | Name  | Salary  
1  | TEST1 | 100  
2  | TEST2 | 200  
3  | TEST3 | 300  

Table B  

Id | Name  | Salary  
1  | TEST1 | 100  
2  | TEST2 | 200  
4  | TEST4 | 400
```

What I want to do is remove similar data from both the tables and do a comparison to check differences between data based on primary key. Suppose `id` is my primary key.

I have used below query. It eliminates the equal data, join remaining data using primary key and displays data from two tables in two sections so that I can check the differences using some text comparison tools by taking result into csv or excel.

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TABLE2) T1 
     JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TABLE1 ) T2 ON T1.id = T2.id 

SELECT T2.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TABLE2) T1 
     JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM TABLE1 ) T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

It works fine for small data sets, however this fails for large data sets with the following error message:

> The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases

I would like know

- How can I minimize the logs to prevent the log errors.
- How much my db instance size and log size should be to handle the above scenario.

Comment: Indexes? Query plan?

Comment: There are no indexes

Comment: You definitely need an index on your join field. Try that out. If there are still problems, let's see the query plan.

Comment: I think if you re-organize the queries to use only joins without subqueries, the problem will not exist.

Comment: @SkinnyJ Actually I'm loading those two tables with data from two data files so I'm not sure whether the file will have any identify column. Some times identify column my be combination of two columns from file.

Answer (score 2):

Try This ...

```
SELECT T1.* 
INTO #tmp1
FROM Table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON  T1.id = T2.id 
WHERE T2.id IS NULL

SELECT T2.* 
INTO #tmp2
FROM Table2 T2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 T1 ON  T2.id = T1.id 
WHERE T1.id IS NULL

SELECT * 
FROM #tmp1
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM #tmp2

DROP TABLE #tmp1
DROP TABLE #tmp2
```

Its Worked .... You Should Try This....

Answer (score 1):

Observe/execute the following script. It results in 4 resultsets, the first two being equal and last two also being equal. I checked the execution plan of the reworded queries and they are much simpler. It is quite possible they will not use the tempdb as much.

Also it would be wise to add an `INDEX` on the `id` column. That would certainly speed things up.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name NVARCHAR(256), salary NUMERIC(28,2));
CREATE TABLE #T2(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name NVARCHAR(256), salary NUMERIC(28,2));

INSERT INTO #T1(id,name,salary)VALUES(1,N'TT',25000),(2,N'Michael',25000),(3,N'Zara',30000),(4,N'Pol',60000),(7,N'Brad',25000);
INSERT INTO #T2(id,name,salary)VALUES(1,N'TT',25000),(2,N'Templeton',25000),(3,N'Zara',25000),(4,N'Jack',60000),(5,N'Pippa',25000);

SELECT 
    T1.* 
FROM 
    #T1 AS T1 
    INNER JOIN #T2 AS T2 ON 
        T2.id=T1.id 
WHERE 
    T2.name<>T1.name OR
    T2.salary<>T1.salary;

SELECT TT1.*
FROM (SELECT*FROM #T1 EXCEPT SELECT*FROM #T2) AS TT1
     JOIN (SELECT*FROM #T2 EXCEPT SELECT*FROM #T1) AS TT2 ON TT2.id=TT1.id;

SELECT 
    T2.* 
FROM 
    #T2 AS T2 
    INNER JOIN #T1 AS T1 ON T1.id=T2.id 
WHERE 
    T1.name<>T2.name OR
    T1.salary<>T2.salary;

SELECT TT2.* 
FROM (SELECT*FROM #T1 EXCEPT SELECT*FROM #T2) AS TT1
     JOIN (SELECT*FROM #T2 EXCEPT SELECT*FROM #T1) AS TT2 ON TT2.id=TT1.id;

DROP TABLE #T1;
DROP TABLE #T2;
```